# Security considerations when enabling user API access

Tags: api

What are the security considerations to take into account when enabling API access?

What items are accessible in apex, queries and other places? How about things like custom settings, encryption keys, etc?

What does user can and cannot execute via execute anonymous?

Answer (score 0):

You enable API access via profiles or permission sets so whatever access that you have specified in that profile and permission set defines what is accessible via API.

To answer your question about the execute anonymous I would like to refer you to the following link where is described what exactly is meant with anonymous blocks and what is allowed.
[Anonymous Blocks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_anonymous_block.htm)

Comment: It's kind of conflicting information there. For example it states you can run `Any built-in Apex methods that are part of the Apex language`, but I wasn't able to run `System.Crypto.signWithCertificate()`.

Comment: Why weren't you? Did you get any errors? Do you have a code sample?

Comment: I got a generic security exception. I mean that's a good thing, but I am sure there are plenty of vectors in API that I haven't considered, hence I am looking for a overview. I am sure people done it before. Allowing API access to your systems is extremely insecure.

Comment: I am still convinced that whatever access you have via API is depending on the access that is given in your users profile.